# How to query a field in a user defined type in a set using CQL (Cassandra)

Tags: cassandra, set, cql, user-defined-types

I am using the User Defined Types in CQL 3.1 (cqlsh info below):

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
```

I have created the following user-defined type (simplified here for demonstration purposes):

```
create type fullname ( firstname text, lastname text );
```

I then created a table that includes a set of type fulsome:

```
create table people ( id UUID primary key, names set < frozen <fullname>> );
```

I can insert rows into the table using:

```
insert into people (id, names) values (
  now(), 
  {{firstname: 'Jim', lastname: 'Jones'}}
);
```

The result looks good:

```
select * from people;

 id                                   | names
--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------
 69ba9d60-a06b-11e4-9923-0fa29ba414fb | {{firstname: 'Jim', lastname: 'Jones'}}
```

My question is this:  how do I fetch all of the first name entries?  If I was not using set, and just fullname, I could use the dot notation:

```
select name.firstname from people;
```

But that obviously doesn't work, because I am using a set.  In normal usage (without a UDT), a set would never have need for dot notation, because all of the entries would be of a simple type (text, UUID, etc).  I tried using all of the usual suspects from other programming languages...

```
select names.firstname...
select names[].firstname...
select names['firstname']...
```

About the only information on UDT's on the web is from the [DataStax web site](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html), which doesn't get into this use case.

Anybody tried this before?  Or is what I am doing just plain not allowed?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 5):

I went ahead and tried this myself.  You're right about being able to pull back a single property if your UDT was not in a set.  But when it's in a collection ( I tried both `SET` and `MAP` types) it doesn't work.  I'm thinking that this is more of a limitation on collections than it is on UDTs.

If you read through the DataStax doc [Using Collections](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html), you'll notice that none of the examples show how to pull back a single element of a collection.  Which is what you would first have to do, before having access to a property on the UDT element.  Anyway, that has to do with how collections are treated as a column, and thus the entire column value is returned on a query.

There is a JIRA ticket currently open for this ([CASSANDRA-7396](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7396)) and additional functionality.  So I'm thinking we'll see it in the semi-near future.  But for now, this isn't going to be possible.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but i found this artical very useful [CQL 2.1 Improvement](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-1)

In short, UDT are written as a blob, so you will always write/read whole data. You can't use only one field of type in where clause. You have to provide all fields.

See also [Example of UDT](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html)